# I am getting "Error No test match your filter" on my Test cafe framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, testcafe

So i have about 35 test cases within the class with all reusable methods for the login and Creds . all the test cases are passing but  one is failing  and getting the Error No test match your filter ! Please if anyone can help . thanks :)

tried to put some Wait but did not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.